# What are the Anemoi's associations?

Tags: greek

The Anemoi are the Greek gods of winds each one with its own direction and as a   harbinger of seasonal winds. Eg. Boreas (god of the North wind) is associated with the cold winds of winter.

The 4 chief gods are Boreas, Zephyrus, Notos and Eurus.

Notos (god of the South wind) and Eurus (god of the East wind) are associated with which seasons and what kind of winds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each of these was associated with a season--Boreas was the cold breath of winter, Zephyros the god of spring breezes, and Notos the god of summer rain-storms.

So note that Eurus was not associated with them, as there were only 3 seasons to the greeks.

From the [anemoi](http://www.theoi.com/Titan/Anemoi.html) article.

> (*summary*) In the Orphic Hymns the Winds were hymned as the gods of the seasons--Zephyros (Zephyrus) was spring, Notos (Notus) summer, and Boreas winter. The early Greeks only recognised three, rather than four, seasons. The fourth Wind, Euros (Eurus), is similarly absent from Homer and Hesiod.
>
> *Orphic Hymn 80 to Boreas* (trans. Taylor) (Greek hymns C3rd B.C. to 2nd A.D.) :
>   "To Boreas (the North-Wind), Fumigation from Frankincense. Boreas, whose wintry blasts, terrific, tear the bosom of the deep surrounding air; cold icy power, approach, and favouring blow, and Thrake (Thrace) awhile desert, exposed to snow: the air's all-misty darkening state dissolve, with pregnant clouds whose frames in showers resolve. Serenely temper all within the sky, and wipe from moisture aither's splendid eye."
>
> *Orphic Hymn 81 to Zephyrus* :
>   "To Zephyros (Zephyrus, the West-Wind), Fumigation from Frankincense. Sea-born, aerial, blowing from the west, sweet Breezes (Aurai, Aurae), who give to wearied labour rest. Vernal and grassy, and of murmuring sound, to ships delightful through the sea profound; for these, impelled by you with gentle force, pursue with prosperous fate their destined course. With blameless gales regard my suppliant prayer, Zephyros unseen, light-winged, and formed from air."
>
> *Orphic Hymn 82 to Notus :*
>   "To Notos (Notus, the South-Wind), Fumigation from Frankincense. Wide-coursing gales, whose lightly leaping feet with rapid wings the air's wet bosom beat, approach, benevolent, swift-whirling powers, with humid clouds the principles of showers; for showery clouds are portioned to your care, to send on earth from all-surrounding air. Hear, blessed power, these holy rites attend, and fruitful rains on earth all-parent send."